# I am looking for data on temperature by country

Tags: uses-of-open-data, climate, africa

I would like to performed a spatiotemporal study on COVID-19 in Africa. I would like to study the impact of temperature on COVID-19, but I don't know if there are temperature data for African countries (by country or region).

I am looking for recent and open data on temperature (over several periods) in Africa.

Comment: Averaging the temperature over an entire country may not be very meaningful.  There are large differences between coasts and inland regions, between valleys and mountains, deserts and swamps, and of course between north and south (unless near the equator).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Global Climate monitor]

You can try:

https://www.globalclimatemonitor.org/#

There you can select data by country and of course you can download time series data.